# nvm unable to switch version , show me error exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%:

Tags: nvm

C:\Users\HP>nvm list

- 16.13.0 (Currently using 64-bit executable)
  15.0.0

C:\Users\HP>nvm use 15.0.0
exec: "cmd": executable file not found in %PATH%:

C:\Users\HP>nvm root

Current Root: C:\Users\HP\AppData\Roaming\nvm

C:\Users\HP>

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 4):

Run `nvm use 15.0.0` again as administrator, this works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when i tried on vscode terminal, but I tried this on cmd instead of vscode terminal,
opened as administrator on cmd,
`nvm use [version needed]`
and it worked, even when I looked up `nvm list` on vscode terminal it was changed to my desired version